# How can I get "watch": "npm run development -- --watch", on my script?

Tags: html, css, npm, sass, watch

How can I get `"watch": "npm run development -- --watch", on my script inside package.json? I have an error` ERR! missing script: watch`

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json file, add the following line under the "scripts" tag like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --progress --profile",
  "watch": "webpack --progress --profile --watch"
},
```